# Trying to relate two variables in R

Tags: r

I have been given a data set and I would like to compare the AGE of people who smoke and who do not smoke. How would i sort the data by people who smoke and their respective ages. Sorry I am really new to R and most of the videos supplied do not provided are not helpful.

EDIT:
So im given dataset with ages, Smoke or not (1,2)

```
AGE  SMOKE
24      1
56      2
21      2 
34      2  
17      1
33      1
```

I am asked to find the average age of people who smoke and who do not smoke and do a hypothesis testing. comparing the two samples.

But first i am struggling on how to seperate the two columns of data, similar to this

```
Smoke       Not Smoke
56              24 
21              17
34              33
```

Sorry, im still very new to R

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

if smoking or not is an attribute of your data frame, you can use something like

```
sample %>% filter(smoke == FALSE) %>% arrange(age)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kabocha Porter's answer is a correct one, though it requires the *dplyr* library in order to be of help. The way to do it with native R syntax would in this case be:

```
sample[sample$smoke == False,]
sample[order(sample$age, decreasing = F),]
```

I actually do this process with *dplyr* too whenever I need it, but understanding the basic syntax may be of help, as this filtering & sorting logic (the one used by base R) is actually what you'll find in Python and in other languages requiring data table manipulations. Cheers!